# Is it possible to name column by index

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am wondering if it is possible to use SQL to create a table that name columns by index(number). Say, I would like to create a table with 10 million or so columns, I definitely don't want to name every column...

I know that I can write a script to generate a long string as SQL command. However, I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to so

Like something I make up here:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
number_columns 10000000,
data_type INT
)
```

---

I guess saying 10 million columns caused a lot of confusion. Sorry about that. I looked up the manual of several major commercial DBMS and seems it is not possible. Thank you for pointing this out.

But another question, which is most important, does SQL support numerical naming of columns, say all the columns have the same type and there is 50 columns. And when referring it, just like

```
SELECT COL.INDEX(3), COL.INDEX(2) FROM MYTABLE
```

Does the language support that?

Comment: I hope you aren't serious about trying to create a table with 10 million columns...

Comment: I'd suggest turning your database diagram about 90 degrees

Comment: Thanks... I am just wondering if the language supports this sort of operations.

Comment: I don't think you can generate so many columns in a table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: I'm not aware of _any_ major RDBMS that allows anything in the range of **10,000** columns, and most probably cap out in the low thousands.  But it raises a question of what problem you're trying to solve - especially as you don't want to 'name all the columns'.  Most of the time, you _want_ to name them all.  As others have suggested, you probably need to rethink this.

Comment: You want an array. Not saying it would be a good design in your case.

Comment: Tell us where you want to go instead of asking about the path you have already chosen. I suspect what you actually need is a pretty standard one-to-many relationship, but I can't be sure until you provide more info.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't resist looking into this, and found that the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html) say "no" to this, that

> There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective
>   maximum may be less for a given table

Comment: Thanks... Inspired by your reply, I looked up postgreSQL as well, Maximum Columns per Table 250 - 1600 depending on column types, not much better...

Comment: I think you need to do some reading about what the "relational" part of using a database is all about - no offense, but even pondering that many columns suggests that you're missing a key element of how a database should be used. :)

Comment: That's fine... I am a non-SQL Database researcher, and doing something SQL can't do is exactly my job... But even for 100 columns, I still don't want to name them one by one. Does the language support numerical naming?

Comment: Pretty sure most standard characters are allowed, but prefixing with numbers, IMHO, is generally not best practices.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html for all the ins and outs of it though.

Comment: If you're working with temporary tables, and remain under the 4K limit, you can add columns (with numbers in the name) by executing SQL statements like this:  ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN mycolumn_1 VARCHAR(50)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* easily do that in **Postgres** with **dynamic SQL**. Consider the demo:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE '
    CREATE TEMP TABLE t ('
    || (
        SELECT string_agg('col' || g || ' int', ', ')
        FROM generate_series(1, 10) g  -- or 1600?
        )
    || ')';
END;
$$;
```

**But why** would you even want to give life to such a monstrosity?

As @A.H. commented, there is a hard limit on the [number of columns in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-basics.html):

> There is a limit on how many columns a table can contain. Depending on
>   the column types, it is **between 250 and 1600**. However, defining a
>   table with anywhere near this many columns is highly unusual and often
>   a questionable design.

Emphasis mine.
More about [table limitations in the Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ?nocache=0.74615200%201339778561#What_is_the_maximum_size_for_a_row.2C_a_table.2C_and_a_database.3F).

---

#### Access columns by index number

As to your additional question: with a schema like the above you can simply write:

```
SELECT col3, col2 FROM t;
```

I don't know of a built-in way to reference columns by index. You can use dynamic SQL again. Or, for a table that consists of integer columns exclusively, this will work, too:

```
SELECT c[3] AS col3, c[2] AS col2
FROM  (
    SELECT translate(t::text, '()', '{}')::int[] AS c -- transform row to ARRAY
    FROM   t
    ) x
```

Comment: The `100000` should be more like `1600`.

Comment: @A.H.: Right! I wasn't even aware of that. The limit should never be of relevance in a halfway decent db design.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when working with databases your schema should be more or less "defined" so dynamic column adding isn't a built in functionality.

You can, however, run a loop and continually `ALTER TABLE` to add columns like so:

```
BEGIN
    SET @col_index = 0;
    start_loop: LOOP
        SET @col_index = @col_index + 1;
        IF @col_index <= num_columns THEN
            SET @alter_query = (SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN added_column_',@col_index,' VARCHAR(50)'));
            PREPARE stmt FROM @alter_query;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
            ITERATE start_loop;
        END IF;
        LEAVE start_loop;
    END LOOP start_loop;
END;
```

But again, like most of the advice you have been given, if you think you need that many columns, you probably need to take a look at your database design, I have personally never heard of a case that would need that.

Comment: This is even worse than using a programming language script to generate a long create table command string. The column doesn't need to be dynamic at all. I am developing new data models. And happy to know the limitation of relational and SQL.

Comment: Agreed, the performance compared to generating this from your app won't be better. I was under the impression you wanted a SQL query to generate `n` number of columns for you and that is exactly what this does. I guess I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Note: As mentioned by @GDP you can have only 4096 cols and definitely the idea is not appreciated and as again @GDP said that database design ideas need to be explored to consider if something else could be a better way to handle this requirement.

However, I was just wondering apart from the absurd requirement if ever I need to do this how can I do it? I thought why not create a custom / user defined MySQL function e.g. create_table() tht will receive the parameters you intend to send and which will in turn generate the required `CREATE TABLE` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is an option for finding columns using ordinal values. It might not be the most elegant or efficient but it works. I am using it to create a new table for faster mappings between data that I need to parse through all the columns / rows.

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnNames TABLE (colName varchar(64), colIndex int)
DECLARE @TableName varchar(64) = 'YOURTABLE' --Table Name
DECLARE @rowNumber int = 2 -- y axis
DECLARE @colNumber int = 24 -- x axis

DECLARE @myColumnToOrderBy varchar(64) = 'ID' --use primary key

--Store column names in a temp table
INSERT INTO @columnNames (colName, colIndex)
SELECT COL.name AS ColumnName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM sys.tables AS TAB
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS COL ON COL.object_id = TAB.object_id
    WHERE TAB.name = @TableName
    ORDER BY COL.column_id;

DECLARE @colName varchar(64)
SELECT @colName = colName FROM @columnNames WHERE colIndex = @colNumber

--Create Dynamic Query to retrieve the x,y coordinates from table
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @colName + ' FROM (SELECT ' + @colName + ', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @myColumnToOrderBy+ ') AS RowNum FROM ' + @tableName + ') t2 WHERE RowNum = ' + CAST(@rowNumber AS varchar(5))
EXEC(@sqlCommand)
```